# Is it possible to disable perforce RCS keyword expansion ($Id$)?

Tags: perforce

Perforce keeps RCS keywords unexpanded on server, but whenever you get latest it expand them. This makes it difficult when comparing changes between different branches using third-party tools.

Is it possible to disable this behavior for a particular workspace or user?

As I understand it is possible to adjust this behavior per file by modifying file type:
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3482

By I cannot modify those files on the server, so I am looking for a client-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You change the filetype from the client. From the command line, if I have, say, a text file with RCS keywords enabled and I want it disabled, I do:

`p4 reopen -c default -t text //depot/path/file.txt`

Or, from P4V, right-click on the file, choose "Change Filetype..." and deselect "+k RCS Keyword Expansion".

Comment: Interesting, so that change would be specific to workspace only, will not affect the depot? I will just have to figure out how to do it recursively for every fire in a tree.

Comment: It will affect that file, in the depot, for everyone.

Comment: OK, seems like, as it adds the updated file to a pending changelist, so I suppose there is no way to disable expansion without modifying files in depot.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, yes, you can remove the RCS keyword filetype for every file (or, at least files of the same type) all at once. Easiest from P4V (if you have various filetypes you want to preserve, do them in batches).